# writiting the code with the appropriate variable values

Tags: java, loops, variables, for-loop, lines

I should Write a program Square.java that declares and initalizes a variable n (with n ≥ 2) and prints out a two dimensional n-by-n triangular pattern as shown below (where n=6).

```
public class Square {
    public static void main (String[]args){
        for (int Line=1; Line<= 6; Line ++){
            for (int n=1; n<= (Line-1*1); n++) {
                System.out.print ("# ");
            }
            for (int n=1; n<= (7-Line); n++){
                System.out.print ("$ ");
            }
            System.out.println ("");
        }
    }
}
```

I can't manage to write the code with `n>=6` or `n=2`

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code - it's *really* hard to read at the moment. Next, it's hard to tell what you're really asking...

Comment: i agree on @Jon's suggestion, please give in an more clear approach.

Comment: You have two variable n in your code, none of them initialized to 6. Also `(Line-1*1)` is interpreted as `(Line(-1*1))`.
What should it print? Can you provide a correct example of output?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are forgetting to update the 7 when you change the 6. Put your size in a variable as shown below. Seems to work for me for 2 and any other size

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int size = 6;

    for (int Line = 1; Line <= size; Line++) {
        for (int n = 1; n <= (Line - 1 * 1); n++) {
            System.out.print("# ");
        }
        for (int n = 1; n <= ((size + 1) - Line); n++) {
            System.out.print("$ ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The size of the square must be an attribut of the class

The result :

```
public class Square {
public int size;

public Square(int size) {
    this.size = size;
}

public void goSquare(){            
    for (int line=1; line<= size; line++){
        for (int n=1; n<= (line-1); n++) {
            System.out.print ("# ");
        }
        for (int n=1; n<= ((size+1)-line); n++){
            System.out.print ("$ ");
        }
        System.out.println ("");
    }
}

public static void main (String[]args){
    Square square = new Square(6);
    square.goSquare();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your actual code `7-Line` is what blocks values `>=6` and for value `=2` your code works great but it only prints one element(point).

Another thing if you use `Line-1*1` you mean `(Line-1)*1` which is equivalent to write `Line-1`.

Also in `7-Line` the value `7` should be an attribute to be used in the first loop too in `Line <= 7`, you can see it in this working code:

```
int max = 2;
for (int Line = 1; Line <= max; Line++) {
  for (int n = 1; n <= (Line - 1); n++) {
    System.out.print("# ");
  }
  for (int n = 1; n <= (max - Line); n++) {
    System.out.print("$ ");
  }
  System.out.println("");
}
```

And this is an **[Ideone Working Example](https://ideone.com/vLpRke)** of the code.